# Ubuntuでvimを使って c++を書きたい、その際に色をつけたい

Tags: vim, ubuntu

Ubuntuでvimを使ってプログラムを書きたいです。 `vim c++ color scheme`で検索すると色の設定が調べられることができますが、肝心のvimがまだインストールすらされていません。
どのようなコマンドを入力して色を適用すればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

まず、
`sudo apt-get install vim`でvimをインストールします。
次にプログラムの中の構文に色をつける(syntax highlight)には下のようにします

(1) 下記のコマンドでvimrc ファイル(vimの設定ファイル)を開く。 vimの設定ファイルはホームディレクトリのvimrcファイルです。

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

(2) 開いたファイルに
`syntax on`
を追加する

(3) ノーマルモードに移行(Escキーを押す)し、`:w`と入力し、Enter で保存して、ノーマルモードで`:source ~/.vimrc`として、コマンドを実行しvimrcを再読み込みする

(1)から(3)の手順で色がつくようになるかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

でいかがでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

## Vim のインストール

`apt-get` で Vim をインストールするのコマンドは

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

でも、そうしたら、まだクリップボードを利用できません。その上

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
```

すれば良いです。[この質問](https://askubuntu.com/a/434994/259705)をご参考ください。

## 色のつけ方

`~/.vimrc` を編集して、下記の内容を上乗せして

```
syntax on
```

次回 vim 起動時、色がついた状態です。

また、`.vimrc` に `colorscheme X` を追加したら、配色を選択できます。例えば

```
colorscheme evening
```

配色のリストは、`ls -l /usr/share/vim/vim__/colors` で見つけ出せます。(`__` はインストールした vim のバージョン番号です。)